# Using Android licensing without an activity

Tags: android

I've released a "Lite" version of an app that I want to then sell the "pro" "upgrade" for - without having to release a totally new version.

My thought was to create a listener that would listen for an intent from the main application, triggering it to query the license service for itself and return to the original application the results. That way you install the trial and buy the "pro" license file essentially without having to reinstall or lose your data from the original install.

I started the license "listener" app which is not going to have it's own activity.  Unfortunately I found that code I've used before to access the license service won't work because I'm trying to run it inside a listener - but getContentResolver() doesn't exist for a listener.

Am I even going down the right road with this approach or is there an easier way?

Comment: Is it not possible to have the main app setup a LicenseChecker that utilizes the package name from the OTHER license pack to see if it's installed?  that way the license pack app doesn't actually have to DO anything at all.

Comment: Well nevermind on that - you can't apply the  CheckLicense permission to a free application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used it in a ContentProvider so I assume you can use it in anything else.

If you have a broadcast receiver though, it might be difficult because the life cycle of a broadcast receiver.

You could sell the "license pack" as a separate service or broadcast receiver, and it can perform the authentication on request.

Comment: When using a ContentProvider, isn't it blocking application process until you get a result back?

Comment: LicenseService is non-blocking/runs in it's own thread. It might keep the process alive, but the ContentProvider will still return a result before Licensing finishes. I just had it nag the user, after it already used the content.

Comment: Thanks.  I just finished writing a ContentProvider for it.  I have the app first try to check the ContentProvider when it's opened, but I don't need the result right then.  Right before I let the user do something that requires the license, I check again, by which time it already has an answer.